# ImageView within RelativeLayout has top and bottom padding

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-imageview

I have a 640px wide, 208px tall PNG that I've placed in my /drawable folder and I'm having a very hard time properly placing it in an ImageView. I want to scale the image so that it maxes out the horizontal resolution, and I want it to scale vertically only as much as it takes to stay in proportion.

The problem I am having is that my ImageView ends up taller than it needs to be to fit the image. The image itself looks perfect; as wide as the screen and in proportion. But the ImageView appears to have padding on the top and bottom. From what I can tell it's the drawable that the ImageView contains that's actually too tall.

I can't post an image because I'm new to SO, but if I did it would be of the Graphical Layout view. When I click on the ImageView the regular blue box shows up around it, but with padding on the top and bottom, the same padding I'm seeing on the device. Even if I drag the blue box to attempt to resize the ImageView, I am not allowed to make it any smaller than it already is (perhaps because the ImageView thinks the drawable is that tall, or something). From what I can tell, this may have something to do with the density of the image...the ImageView ends up being 312 pixels tall (208*1.5) on an hdpi device.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView android:id="@+id/back" android:src="@drawable/categoryheader2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </ImageView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I guess [android:adjustViewBounds](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:adjustViewBounds)="true" on the ImageView should do the trick. I recently had a similar problem, when I was trying to [scale an image to fit the whole width of the view without loosing its proportions](http://convales.blogspot.de/2012/05/android-imageview-and-bitmapdrawable.html).

Comment: old question but still comes up here in there in my app - thanks for responding! I'll give it a try and accept the answer if it works!

Comment: Really a shame that you didn't get an answered mark.
But you saved me some searches thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is probably so standard to know this, that very few ask it, for me as a beginner it came in quite handy.

Answer (score 1):

did you tried the tag :  `android:scaleType="fitXY"` or `android:scaleType="centerCrop"` on your `ImageView` ?

Comment: thanks for your response, but none of the scaletypes work. fitXY just makes the image taller to fit (removing the "padding" but messing up the proportions of the image), centerCrop also makes the image taller, but makes it wider as well to stay in proportion, but of course now the sides are cropped. :(